# Detect which uitextfield called the uikeyboard

Tags: objective-c

After a lot of trouble I was able to add a RETURN button to a numerical key pad.

I want to delete it when introduciing other data  into other uitextfields because currently that button appears everytime I use the keyboard, it's part of the keyboard.

Im adding the event handler on KeyBoardDidShow, otherwise it doesnt work,

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
```

Then in KeyboarWillShow

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note {  

    // create custom button

    NSLog(@"El note es: %@", note);

    UIButton *doneButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    doneButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 163, 106, 53);
    doneButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
    [doneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"done.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [doneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"done_pressed.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [doneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doneButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIWindow *keyboardWindow = nil;
    for (UIWindow *testWindow in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]) {
        if (![[testWindow class] isEqual:[UIWindow class]]) {
            keyboardWindow = testWindow;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!keyboardWindow) return;

    // Locate UIKeyboard.
    UIView *foundKeyboard = nil;
    for (UIView *possibleKeyboard in [keyboardWindow subviews]) {

        // iOS 4 sticks the UIKeyboard inside a UIPeripheralHostView.
        if ([[possibleKeyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIPeripheralHostView"]) {
            possibleKeyboard = [[possibleKeyboard subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
        }

        if ([[possibleKeyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIKeyboard"]) {
            foundKeyboard = possibleKeyboard;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (foundKeyboard) {
        // Add the button to foundKeyboard.
        [foundKeyboard addSubview:doneButton];

    }
}
```

The thing is that this creates the button always! Obviously! I would like to create the button only in certains uitextfields, not in all, but how to do that?

The method - (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing: doesnt execute the first time, only the rest, why? Dont know, but if I was able to know which uitextfield is calling the keyboard my hair would grow again and I'd be slimmer, anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`textFieldShouldBeginEditing:` only fires consistently if each and every one of your text fields have delegates set properly (check your XIB).

And then you can set a tag value in your text fields.  You can display the Return button for fields with tag 1 and no Return button for fields with tag 0.

Comment: Ok, I fixed the delegate's for the uitextfields. But the problem is that when textFieldShouldBeginEditing: is executed the keyboard is not loaded, therefore I cant add the return button there, since the keyboard view is not accesisble. It is accesible from keyboardwillshow but there I cant access to the info of each uitextfield. Should I keep an attribute that saves which uitextfield was the last one to be tapped?

Comment: yep... keeping an attribute which saves the last UITextField should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to  count the number of subviews inside the keyboard to know how many keys it has. That is a bad hack, but you already have a bad hack to find the keyboard :-)

Also another suggestion:

```
 if (foundKeyboard) {
    UIView *doneButton = [foundKeyboard viewWithTag:BUTTON_TAG];

    if(numPad){
        if(buttonView==nil){
            //create doneButton
            [foundKeyboard addSubview:doneButton];          
        }
    }else{  
        [doneButton removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```